# intersection of np.array and set

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, set

I would like to intersect an np.array with a set without having to convert the np.array to a list first (slows down the program to an unworkable level).

Here's my current code: (Note that I'm getting this data from b,g,r rawCapture, and selection_data is simply a set from beforehand.)

```
def GreenCalculations(data):
    data.reshape(1,-1,3)
    data={tuple(item) for item in data[0]}
    ColourCount=selection_data & set(data)
    Return ColourCount
```

Now my current issue I think is that I'm only comparing the first top part of the picture, due to data[0]. Is it possible to loop through all the rows?

Note: tolist() takes lots of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a sample `data`; I'm guessing it's a nxnx3 array, with dtype `uint8`

```
In [791]: data=np.random.randint(0,256,(8,8,3),dtype=np.uint8)
```

`reshape` method returns a new array with new shape, but doesn't change that in inplace:

```
In [793]: data.reshape(1,-1,3)
```

`data.shape=(1,-1,3)` would do that inplace.  But why the initial `1`?

Instead:

```
In [795]: aset={tuple(item) for item in data.reshape(-1,3)}
In [796]: aset
Out[796]: 
{(3, 92, 60),
 (5, 211, 227),
 (6, 185, 183),
 (9, 37, 0),
 ....

 In [797]: len(aset)
 Out[797]: 64
```

In my case a set of 64 unique items - not surprising given how I generated the values

Your do-nothing `data.reshape` line and `{tuple(item) for item in data[0]}` accounts for why it seem to be working on just the 1st row of the picture.

I'm guessing `selection_data` is similar 3 item tuples, such as:

```
In [801]: selection_data = {tuple(data[1,3,:]), (1,2,3), tuple(data[5,5,:])}
In [802]: selection_data
Out[802]: {(1, 2, 3), (49, 132, 26), (76, 131, 16)}
In [803]: selection_data&aset
Out[803]: {(49, 132, 26), (76, 131, 16)}
```

You don't say where you attempt to use `tolist`, but I'm guessing in generating the set of tuples.

But curiously, `tolist` speeds up the conversion:

```
In [808]: timeit {tuple(item) for item in data.reshape(-1,3).tolist()}
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.7 µs per loop
In [809]: timeit {tuple(item) for item in data.reshape(-1,3)}
1000 loops, best of 3: 239 µs per loop
In [815]: timeit data.reshape(-1,3).tolist()
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.8 µs per loop
In [817]: timeit {tuple(item.tolist()) for item in data.reshape(-1,3)}
10000 loops, best of 3: 100 µs per loop
```

So for doing this sort of list and set operation, we might as well jump to the list format right away.

`numpy` has some set functions, for example `np.in1d`.  That only operations on 1d arrays, but as has been demonstrated in some `unique row` questions, we can get around that by viewing the 2d array as a structured array.  I had to fiddle around to get this far:

```
In [880]: dt=np.dtype('uint8,uint8,uint8')
In [881]: data1=data.reshape(-1,3).view(dt).ravel()
In [882]: data1
Out[882]: 
array([(41, 145, 254), (138, 144, 7), (192, 241, 203), (42, 177, 215),
       (78, 132, 87), (221, 176, 87), (107, 171, 147), (231, 13, 53),
       ... 
      dtype=[('f0', 'u1'), ('f1', 'u1'), ('f2', 'u1')])
```

Construct a selection with the same structured array nature:

```
In [883]: selection=[data[1,3,:],[1,2,3],data[5,5,:]]
In [885]: selection=np.array(selection,np.uint8).view(dt)
In [886]: selection
Out[886]: 
array([[(49, 132, 26)],
       [(1, 2, 3)],
       [(76, 131, 16)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'u1'), ('f1', 'u1'), ('f2', 'u1')])
```

So the items in `selection` that are also found in `data1` are:

```
In [888]: np.in1d(selection,data1)
Out[888]: array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

and the items in `data1` that are in selection are:

```
In [890]: np.where(np.in1d(data1,selection))
Out[890]: (array([11, 45], dtype=int32),)
```

or in the unraveled shape

```
In [891]: np.where(np.in1d(data1,selection).reshape(8,8))
Out[891]: (array([1, 5], dtype=int32), array([3, 5], dtype=int32))
```

the same (1,3) and (5,5) items I used to generate `selection`.

The `in1d` timings are competitive:

```
In [892]: %%timeit
     ...: data1=data.reshape(-1,3).view(dt).ravel()
     ...: np.in1d(data1,selection)
     ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 65.7 µs per loop

In [894]: timeit selection_data&{tuple(item) for item in data.reshape(-1,3).tolist()}
10000 loops, best of 3: 91.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: It's expected that `tolist` will speed up the conversion. Numpy objects store the data as raw values, not as python objects. Which means that every access from python requires numpy to create a wrapper object for the value. This is done also when iterating. The `tolist` method creates all the wrappers in one optimized C loop and put them into a python list, the subsequent iteration is over a python list which is fast because it doesn't have to create the wrapper objects.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (and im not 100% sure that i do; but using the same assumptions as hpaulj), your problem can be solved thus using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
ColourCount = npi.intersection(data.reshape(-1, 3), np.asarray(selection_data))
```

That is, it treats both the reshaped array as well as the set as sequences of length-3 ndarrays, of which it finds the intersection in a vectorized manner.